# How to Divide sub queires in the MYSQLSELECT statement?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to divide 2 sub-queries in the select statement how can one do it? 
expected result :

total_completed / total = rate.

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(id)
    FROM   campaign_results)                  AS total,
   (SELECT Count(id)
    FROM   campaign_results
    WHERE  status = 'completed') AS total_completed,
   ( total_completed / total )                AS rate
FROM   `campaigns`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation here and avoid putting subqueries in your select clause:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' THEN 1 END) AS total_completed,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS rate
FROM campaigns;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what result is expected.  The counts are coming from `campaign_results`, but the outer query is from `campaigns` ...  are we trying to get counts for each campaign?

It's hard to tell what the specification is. Without a specification, preferably illustrated with example data and a sample results, we're just guessing.

Given that the example SQL shows tables named `campaigns` and `campaign_results`, and given that the `total` is a count of non-NULL values of id, maybe (and we're just guessing here) the result we're after would be something like the result returned by this query:

```
SELECT c.id
     , r.campaign_id
     , r.total
     , r.total_completed
     , r.total_completed / r.total  AS rate
  FROM campaigns c
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT cr.campaign_id
              , SUM( 1  )       AS total
              , SUM( cr.status = 'COMPLETED' ) AS total_completed 
           FROM campaign_results cr
          GROUP BY cr.campaign_id
       ) r
    ON r.campaign_id = c.id
```

---

This SQL may not satisfy the specification. We're just guessing at a foreign key column `campaign_id` in the `campaign_results` table. The SQL illustrates usage of some very common SQL patterns: `GROUP BY` and conditional aggregation, inline view and outer join.